# Calculation of occurrence of strings

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns, `id`, `name` and `vote`. They're populated with many registers. I need that return the register with the best balance of votes. The votes types are 'yes' and 'no'.

Yes -> Plus 1
No - Minus 1

This column `vote`is a string column. I am using SQL SERVER.

[image]

It must return **Ann** for me

Comment: Hi there, please post table definitions, sample data and expected output.

Comment: What is your definition of "the best balance of votes"?  That could be taken a lot of ways.

Comment: the 'yes' vote increments 1 point, the 'no' vote, decrements 1. The best balance will be the register with 'more points'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using a case a statement you can turn your magic strings into numeric values. These can be summed and a group statement defines how to organize the summation.

Edit: I've added a sort as it is likely you are interested in the "winners".

```
SELECT
    SUM (
        CASE WHEN vote = 'Yes' THEN 1 
        WHEN vote = 'No' THEN -1 
        ELSE 0 END) BalancedVotes,
    Name
FROM 
    myTable
GROUP BY 
    name
ORDER BY 
    BalancedVotes DESC
```

Comment: perfect! It works